# Have Islamic prayers been introduced into Ontario public schools while Christian ones have been removed?

Tags: religion, education, islam, christianity, canada

Recently I saw one of those chain letters circulating that made a number of lurid claims that looked suspect for me. Here's the first such claim:

> Islamic prayers have now been introduced into Toronto and other public schools in Ontario, and, yes, in Ottawa too while the Lord's Prayer was removed (due to being so offensive?! To whom? Not to the vast majority of Canadians!).

Is there any truth to this claim?

Comment: I wanted to edit this to give a link to the source to show it was notable. That turned out to be a story itself. Paul Merek posted an essay on [Celestial Junk](http://cjunk.blogspot.com.au/2006/02/why-peaceful-majority-is-irrelevant.html) that was then [misattributed to Dr Emanuel Tanya](http://www.snopes.com/politics/soapbox/germanislam.asp), and *then* this paragraph was [appended](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130527154348AAKCKdZ).

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Let's break the original claim down into several constituent components.

> Islamic prayers have now been introduced into Toronto and other public schools in Ontario.

[Toronto Sun](http://www.torontosun.com/2012/09/22/muslims-want-permanent-prayer-rooms-in-high-schools), [CBC News](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029160758/http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/toronto/tempers-flare-over-prayer-in-schools-1.1104775), and [others](http://www.skepticnorth.com/2011/07/a-skeptic%E2%80%99s-take-on-muslim-prayers-in-a-toronto-public-school/) have reported that some Ontario schools provide *prayer space* for devout Muslim children. The original claim is therefore **true, although misleading**. Muslim prayer has been "introduced" only to the extent that a few schools made space available for prayer.

> the Lord's Prayer was removed

[Zylberberg v. Sudbury Board of Education](http://www.canlii.org/en/on/onca/doc/1988/1988canlii189/1988canlii189.html) challenged the use of the Lord’s Prayer in opening exercises in public schools in Ontario in 1988. The [Ontario Court of Appeals](http://aaagnostica.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Zylberberg-v.-Sudbury-Board-of-Education.pdf) ruled that the recitation of the Lord's Prayer ultimately "infringes the Charter freedom of conscience and religion," even in cases where the students were allowed to opt out.

The claim is then again **true, but extremely misleading.** The prayer was "removed" in so far as it could not be used to pressure religious minorities to [conform to the practices of the Christian majority](http://www.chrc-ccdp.ca/en/timePortals/milestones/122mile.asp).

> due to being so offensive?! To whom?

The word "offensive" does not figure prominently in the Canadian ruling in the case of [Zylberberg v. Sudbury Board of Education](http://www.canlii.org/en/on/onca/doc/1988/1988canlii189/1988canlii189.html). The opinion does quote a related American case ([School District of Abington Township, Pennsylvania v. Schempp](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1962/142)), which in 1963 concluded that "a State may require neither public school students nor candidates for an office of public trust to profess beliefs *offensive to religious principles*."<sup>1</sup>

The judge explicitly references a situation where a child of one faith may be pressured to profess a belief in another, as would be the case of Muslim or Jewish children being encouraged to recite Christian prayers.  The claim purports incredulity, where the meaning is plain: **being forced to recite the Lord's Prayer offends those who do not believe in it.**<sup>2</sup>

> Not to the vast majority of Canadians!

The court based their decision in Zylberberg v. Sudbury on its interpretation of the [Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/const/page-15.html) which includes "freedom of conscience and freedom of religion." The charter became a part of the Canadian constitution in 1982 amidst **broad popular support**.<sup>3</sup>

Let's reassemble the original statement without the demagoguery:

> Some schools in Toronto and Ottawa now provide space for Muslims to pray. Meanwhile, our courts found that asking students to recite the Lord's Prayer every morning may offend those not of Christian faith (even when the option to opt out exists). Freedom of conscience and religion is protected by the Canadian constitution, which became law with popular support.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Emphasis mine. The case found also that  "Pennsylvania law and Abington's policy, requiring public school students to participate in classroom religious exercises" violated "the religious freedom of students as protected by the First and Fourteenth Amendments."</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Furthermore, the same judge expressed concern about someone having to "profess publicly his disbelief as the prerequisite to the exercise of his constitutional right of abstention." This means that when someone opts out of prayer they are in essence forced to publicly declare their disbelief. This could lead to ridicule or persecution, for example.</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>See Cairns, Alan C. *Charter versus Federalism: The Dilemmas of Constitutional Reform*. McGill-Queen’s Press, 1992. "The Constitution Act [...] had the broadest base of popular support for any package for constitutional change in Canadian history" (p. 67).</sub>

Comment: Cute rhetorical trick, to use "introduce" and "remove" in the same sentence with meanings that don't correspond.

Comment: This answer employs its own rhethorical trick to mislead. The prayer space has NOT ever been provided to any other religion, including (or especially) Christian. And more speculatively, I'm pretty sure any Christian who tries to use those prayer rooms for their prayer would at best be unwelcome by occupants; at worst, slapped socially or even legally.

Comment: **Please limit your comments to the answer, don't answer other comments if possible.** Also, this question is about Canada, what the law says in the US is irrelevant.

Comment: Further, I would like to remind everyone in this thread the the purpose of this site is to annotate speculative claims with referenced sources. Not all questions can be settled in this way. A critical conversation about religion in school is important, but this is not the best place to have it. I hope that the sources I provided can serve as evidence-based ground for the broader public conversation. You can help by suggesting specific factual references, related to the original claim.

Comment: Great answer.  Muslim faith *requires* this prayer space and it's completely unobtrusive.  Christian faith doesn't *require* reciting the *Lord's Prayer* every morning.  If Christian parent are particularly adamant about this, they are free to do this at home before school.  BTW: I'm a Christian who went to school in Ontario. We also sang the national anthem every morning.

Comment: Out of genuine curiosity: do those schools provide a "generic" space for prayers (for all religions), or a space per religion, or a space for only one religion (Islam in that case)?

Comment: @user2121 Also note that the "removal" that the original claim is howling about is about the fact that schools can no longer *force* non-christian students to recite the Lord's Prayer. No longer being allowed to force your religion on others is neither oppression nor persecution; it's rather the opposite, in fact.

Comment: @Shadur Good point. I do consulting for blue chip corporations.  They all have a prayer space of some sort in their office buildings (which are really quite "generic" and completely unobtrusive).  But I couldn't even begin to image the outcry both internally and in the press if they forced everyone to stand up every morning and recite the *Lord's Prayer*!

Comment: Wait wait, hold on. According to this answer itself, the Lord's Prayer was considered a violation "even in cases where the students were allowed to opt out." Surely by that same logic, the existence of prayer rooms must also be a violation "even in cases where the students [are] allowed to opt out." Is that not a double standard?

Comment: @WolfieInu It's the difference between opt in and opt out. Being told you should do something and then having to stand up and say you won't do it - as opposed to being given the option to do something if you want to. No one "opts out" of the prayer rooms as they would never be taken to them unless they wanted to go there.

Comment: Is that a personal distinction, or a legal distinction? If the latter, fair enough in that case. As long as prayer is not banned (or is banned) irrespective of religion, it's not a double standard.

Comment: Perhaps it's just my English, but I don't get it. "being forced to recite the Lord's Prayer offends those who do not believe in it", "requiring students to recite the Lord's Prayer every morning may offend" - that's understandable, but in the same post you quote an opinion that "recitation of the Lord's Prayer ultimately "infringes the Charter freedom of conscience and religion," even in cases where the students were allowed to opt out". Doesn't the freedom of "opting out" mean that noone is "forced" or "required" to recite anything?

Comment: @denten in your final "without demagoguery" restatement, the phrase "requiring students to recite the Lord's Prayer" is inaccurate.  In Zylberberg v. Sudbury the court acknowledged that no student had been required to recite the prayer, and that all students already had the option of leaving the room during the prayer or staying in the room and not praying.  Also, when the students chose to remain in the room and not pray, they were not required to bow their head.  http://www.thecharterrules.ca/resources/zylberberg_v_sudbury_board_of_education_1988_canlii_189_on_ca.pdf

Comment: @DavePhD the quote is from the appeal. i softened the language and added the citation.